# How can an Azure precompiled C# function build locally in VS2017, but not in VSTS MSBuild?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How can an Azure precompiled C# function locally compile, but not in VSTS?

I've used the latest preview of the Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Azure Functions, along with VS 2017 preview 3 to create a simple HttpTrigger function. The VS sln compiles fine locally.

I can also successfully publish to Azure from VS ... *eventually!!*

First time fails, but shell is created in Azure. Second publish actually gets the json and dll up to Azure.

Thought I'd set up a quick CI build in VSTS, and followed details in [Donna Malayeri](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/06/01/deploying-visual-studio-2017-function-projects-with-vsts/) post.

But VSTS shows loads of errors in the build solution task, e.g.

```
2017-07-11T13:51:59.3254765Z ##[error]SmcPrecompileFunctionApp\TriggerByHttp.cs(14,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FunctionNameAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2017-07-11T13:51:59.3254765Z TriggerByHttp.cs(14,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FunctionNameAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [d:\a\1\s\SmcPrecompileFunctionApp\SmcPrecompileFunctionApp.csproj]
```

Double checked and the agent is set to the Hosted VS2017

Comment: Kind of sounds like the NuGet package failed to install? Any warnings during NuGet package restore in VSTS?

Comment: @juunas The restore task step has got lots of errors around my use of the prerelease bits, e.g. Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (>= 2.1.0-beta1)' for '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest version of NuGet in the NuGet build task. For some reason, lower versions don't restore all the packages correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response ... weird, the NuGet restore works if I set to v1.* but fails with v2.*  ??  Main VSTS build panel shows ... No package sources were found in the NuGet.config file at undefined
Error: d:\a\_tool\NuGet\4.0.0\x64\nuget.exe failed with return code: 1
Packages failed to restore